# How many databases can we create in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: sql, database, google-cloud-platform

I am very new to SQL (or say MYSQL). I am currently working on an application and want to go with multi-tenant data architecture ,ie providing separate database to each client . My question is that is their any limit to how many databases can we create on Google Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 0):

As per [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/database-count-limit.html#:%7E:text=8.4.-,5%20Limits%20on%20Number%20of%20Databases%20and%20Tables,on%20the%20number%20of%20directories.) there is no limit on the number of databases. However, as per [GCP Cloud SQL limit and quota](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quotas#increasing_your_quotas) you can create database as per you requirement and you can increase your quota accordingly.

There are few configurable limits:

- By default, you can have up to 40 instances per project.
- Maximum concurrent connections 4000 for all types of machine except db-f1-micro and db-g1-small
- Table limit will be 10,000 for an instance
- Cloud SQL storage limits Up to 30,720 GB, depending on the machine type

Comment: Brother how much does a database or extra instance cost.
just asking for more info. is my way of managing user info  a good and economic way .. plz let me know.

Comment: Here is the GCP pricing calculator https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator